# CSS classes not loading

Tags: html, css

I am trying to play around with this css package: https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/csshake

I followed the directions, but for some reason the animations aren't available on my page.

here's my head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link type="text/css" href="css/csshake.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

and then in the body I'm trying:

```
<div class="shake shake-constant">shake!</div>
```

If I inspect that element with Chrome dev tools, I can see that none of the css classes are applied to the div. If I change the header to `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/csshake.css">`, then the classes appear in dev tools, but they are listed as invalid property values.

I'm sure I'm missing something really basic, but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the CSS file, it doesn't natively support cross browsers - you'll have to add relevant browser prefixes yourself

For example, `animation-name: shake-base;` only works in browsers that allow un-prefixed values (like new versions of FireFox). To serve Chrome you'd have to add `-webkit-animation-name: shake-base;`

You can use the following tools to let your computer do most of the work for you

- [CSSPrefixer](http://cssprefixer.appspot.com/) (manually)
- [AutoPrefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) (automatic)
- [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/index.php) (manual)
- [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) (automatic)

There are others as well

Comment: Yes. Specifically, -webkit- is needed.

Comment: @bjb568 Thanks, I was adding that in (: